# convert JSON into square bracket format (The JSON Structure)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to convert an array into this **JSON format**!

```
[
    [
        ["SNO",1],
        ["chartType","pie"],
        ["outputValues","rural_total_m,urban_total_m"],
        ["attributeId",10025],
        ["level","india"]
    ],
    [
        ["SNO",2],
        ["chartType","column"],
        ["outputValues","total_m"],
        ["attributeId",10025],
        ["level","state"]
    ]
]
```

I have an array as a result from **sql query** and **print_r()** function of php is printing it as-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SNO] => 1
            [chartType] => pie
            [outputValues] => rural_total_m,urban_total_m
            [attributeId] => 10025
            [level] => india
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [SNO] => 2
            [chartType] => column
            [outputValues] => total_m
            [attributeId] => 10025
            [level] => state
        )
)
```

How can i get the above format?
Thank you!

Comment: The desired format doesn't match the sample data, so it's a bit unclear what you want. How should [1=>7,4,2,8,4,1,9,3,2,16,7,12] be converted to [["a",12],["b",5],["c",18],["d",13],["e",7],["f",4],["g",9]]? If you provide the desired output for the array in question, you'd likely get a better answer.

Comment: Why is 12 the same as `a`? Why is `b` 5? Where is 5 even present?

Comment: Sorry about that, take a,b,c,d,e,f,g as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

Comment: well when i write [1=>7,4,8,.....] the json_encode() function automatically increments from 1 to the number of values.

Comment: i hope it's clear now!

Comment: not really. that's not a valid json

Comment: @SalmanAkhatar `json_encode` isn't doing the incrementing, that's done when you create the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**

if you want something like this

```
[
    [
        ["SNO",1],
        ["chartType","pie"],
        ["outputValues","rural_total_m,urban_total_m"],
        ["attributeId",10025],
        ["level","india"]
    ],[
        ["SNO",2],
        ["chartType","column"],
        ["outputValues","total_m"],
        ["attributeId",10025],
        ["level","state"]
    ]
]
```

then use this code

**let the mock array is $result**

```
$result = array(
                 array(
                    "SNO" => 1,
                    "chartType" => "pie",
                    "outputValues" => "rural_total_m,urban_total_m",
                    "attributeId" => 10025,
                    "level" => "india"
                ),
                 array(
                    "SNO" => 2,
                    "chartType" => "column",
                    "outputValues" => "total_m",
                    "attributeId" => 10025,
                    "level" => "state"
                ) 
        );

$return_array = array();


foreach ($result as $value) {
    $temp_array = array();

    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
        $temp_array[] = array($key,$value);
    }
    $return_array[] = $temp_array;


}

echo json_encode($return_array);
```

else if you desired output is like this one

```
[

    ["SNO",1],
    ["chartType","pie"],
    ["outputValues","rural_total_m,urban_total_m"],
    ["attributeId",10025],
    ["level","india"]
    ["SNO",2],
    ["chartType","column"],
    ["outputValues","total_m"],
    ["attributeId",10025],
    ["level","state"]

]
```

then use this one

$return_array = array();

```
foreach ($result as $value) {

    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
        $return_array[] = array($key,$value);
    }

}
```

**---------------------------------Before Update ----------------------------------------------------**

not the most effective solution, but will do the trick !!

```
$array = array(7,4,2,8,4,1,9,3,2,16,7,12);

$alpha = 'a';
$retur_array = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $retur_array[] = array($alpha++ , $value);
}
json_encode($retur_array);
```

output

```
    [
["a",7],
["b",4],
["c",2],
["d",8],
["e",4],
["f",1],
["g",9],
["h",3],
["i",2],
["j",16],
["k",7],
["l",12]
]
```

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted! But what if i have alpha already defined for each value?

Comment: hmm, so if the alpha  are already define , thay must be in an array or something, so you can search them by index , just change the $alpha = 0;,
if not then can you b a little more explicit that where and how the alpha's are stored!!

Comment: An array defined by select query from sql table! If i am applying the above code on that array it is producing output as
[
[{"key":"value"}],
[{"key":"value"}],
.........
]

Comment: An array defined by select query from sql table! If i am applying the above code on that array it is producing output as
[
[{"key":"value"}],
[{"key":"value"}],
.........
]

and each curly bracket includes not only single value but many!
I think fault in Array!

Comment: if you can please update the question , also put a mock object or array , that you are calling form the db,

Comment: I don't know whether the result returning from db is an Array or Object but i can print it using 
print_r($result)
method in php and its format you can see in question!

Comment: hmm so the "chartType" is what you want for the character and son for the value like
 [  
  [1,"pie"], 
  [2,"column"] 
] ` ??

Answer (score 1):

Yuor input array has the numbers as keys. You need to loop over that and change the keys to values in a sub-array.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $new_array[] = array("$key", $val);
}
echo json_encode($new_array);
```